# Stash: list of related entries completed by recent entries

Tags: stash

What I am trying to do:

- I am in an entry detail page.
- Entries have a playa field to create relationships w/ other entries
- First, I need the first 4 related entries, in the order specified by the user in the Playa field
- Then, I need to add the 4 most recent entries to that list
- Finally, I need to display the first 4 entries of that list (Playa entries + Recent entries) and filter out duplicates

3 possible scenarios

- I have no Playa entries > display just the 4 most recent entries
- I have 4 Playa entries > just display those
- I have a mix of Playa entries and Recent entries. In that case, Playa entries have to be displayed first in the order specified by the user

Here is what I have tried so far

```
{!-- SET Entry data --}
{exp:channel:entries disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks" channel="articles" status="not closed" require_entry="yes" limit="1"}

    {!-- Get first 4 related items in Playa field (combined with latest article and interviews if less than 4 --}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="st_complementary_items" parse_tags="yes"}
        {exp:playa:children channel="articles|interviews" limit="4"}
            {stash:st_complementaryitem_title}{title}{/stash:st_complementaryitem_title}
        {/exp:playa:children}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}


{!-- Get last 4 published articles / interviews items (completes the list if less than 4 in the Playa field  --}
{exp:channel:entries disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks" channel="articles|interviews" status="not closed" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic="no" limit="4"}

    {exp:stash:append_list name="st_complementary_items"}
        {stash:st_complementaryitem_title}{title}{/stash:st_complementaryitem_title}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}


{!-- BUILD page content --}
{exp:stash:set name="content"}

    <p>Total items in list: {exp:stash:list_count name="st_complementary_items"}</p>
    <p>Unique items in list: {exp:stash:list_count name="st_complementary_items" unique="yes"}</p>

    {!-- get the list of related items (Playa + latest if less than 4 playa), still have to make rows unique using the unique=yes parameter --}
    {exp:stash:get_list name="st_complementary_items"}
        <p>[{count}/{total_results}] - {st_complementaryitem_title}</p>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

That works decently well, unless I have no playa items. Then Stash acts as if I have 5 items in my list with a first one that's not parsed.

Total items in list: 5 / Unique items in list: 5

- [1/5] - {st_complementaryitem_title}
- [2/5] - Recent Entry title
- [3/5] - Recent Entry title
- [4/5] - Recent Entry title
- [5/5] - Recent Entry title

I am at loss as to why this is happening.

If I completely remove the recent entries loop and just leave the Playa loop, things work as expected and I get 0 entries.

Grateful if anyone can help me out with that.

**EDIT: [Mark "The" Croxton was quick again](https://twitter.com/croxton/status/391148610743586816): Stash 2.4.4 has been updated to ignore empty list items** which apparently was the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is how I ended up coding this in the end:

```
{!-- Extended page template --}
{stash:embed name="layouts:page"}

{!-- SET Entry data --}
{exp:channel:entries disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks" channel="articles" status="not closed" require_entry="yes" limit="1"}

    {!-- Get first 4 related items in Playa field (combined with latest article and interviews if less than 4 --}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="st_complementary_items" parse_tags="yes"}

        {exp:playa:children channel="articles|interviews" status="not closed" limit="4"}
            {stash:st_complementaryitem_title}{title}{/stash:st_complementaryitem_title}
            {stash:st_complementaryitem_date}{entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}{/stash:st_complementaryitem_date}
            {stash:st_complementaryitem_date_machine}{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}{/stash:st_complementaryitem_date_machine}
        {/exp:playa:children}

    {/exp:stash:set_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}


{!-- Get last 4 published articles / interviews items (completes the list if less than 4 in the Playa field  --}
{exp:channel:entries disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks" channel="articles|interviews" status="not closed" orderby="date" sort="desc" dynamic="no" limit="4"}

    {exp:stash:append_list name="st_complementary_items"}
        {stash:st_complementaryitem_title}{title}{/stash:st_complementaryitem_title}
        {stash:st_complementaryitem_date}{entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}{/stash:st_complementaryitem_date}
        {stash:st_complementaryitem_date_machine}{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}{/stash:st_complementaryitem_date_machine}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- BUILD page content --}
{exp:stash:set name="content"}

        {!-- get the list of related items and make it unique on the titles --}
        {exp:stash:get_list name="st_complementary_items" unique="st_complementaryitem_title"}
            {if count == 1}<ul>{/if}
                <li>[{count}/{total_results}] - {st_complementaryitem_title} - {st_complementaryitem_date} - {st_complementaryitem_type}</li>
            {if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
        {/exp:stash:get_list}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

This ends up meeting all my requirements

- Because the set_list and append list happen in the same "oignon layer" and because the set_list comes first in the code, the playa items are always before the recent items in the stash list
- Playa items are in the order they were entered by the user and recent items are ordered by date
- We get rid of duplicates by using the unique parameter (set on titles) on the get_list tag pair

I first tried to use append_lists in both cases and create a type of "playa" or a type of "recent" that I could use to sort the list when I get it to make sure playa items are always before the recent items.

But then, even using nested lists, I couldn't figure out a way of making the titles unique across the playa and recent entries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things with Stash. I'd use switchee with the variable {exp:playa:total_children}, I'd set up the cases as:

case value ="0" -> display recent entries with exp:channel:entries

case value ="1|2|3" -> display mix of entries
I'd use stash here to retrieve the ids of playa:children and the ids of the most recent entries which I'd then put inside a channel:entries with a limit of 4.

case default (for when there are enough playa entries) -> display playa entries only with exp:playa:children

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that route before. In this case, to deal w/ the mixed case the way you describe I think you need more loops, which is less economical in terms of queries. 1 playa children loop and 1 channel entries loop to get the ids + another channel entries loop to display the data you need from the entries. You also need to pass a few things around (ids of playa and recent entries) + need a way to filter out duplicates. With the solution described above, you just need 2 loops (1 playa and 1 channel entries) and no need to pass variables around.